# BottomNavigation Icon Tint

Tags: android, xml, menu, bottomnavigationview

I just added the BottomNavigation into my android app, but two of my four icons in there don't have the right color.

This is how it looks like in Android Studio Preview:

[image]

And this is how it looks like on the device:

[image]

All the icons are in my drawable folder.

This is the xml for the BottomNavigation:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

And this is the xml for the items:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_48dp"
        android:title="@string/home"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_requests"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_collections_white_48dp"
        android:title="@string/requests"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account_circle_white_48dp"
        android:title="@string/profile"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_recents"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_schedule_white_48dp"
        android:title="@string/recents"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: it seem's there is no problem in your code...but once try to clean project or restart the Studio.

Comment: Okay, after Clean, Rebuild and restart Android Studio, now all 4 Icons show up in bright white. But as soon I click one of them, the last one gets this ugly gray color. After some more clicks on the Items, the second item also falls back to the gray color. Maybe something ist wrong here in the ItemSelectedListener? `case R.id.action_home:
                        replaceFragmentFrame(homeFragment);
                        item.setChecked(true);
                        break;` This is done for every item of course.

Comment: then put your code too.maybe someone will help you.who know your problem.i will tell you if i know.

Answer (score 0):

While making a selector, always keep the default state at the end, otherwise only default state would be used. You need to reorder the items in your selector as:

And the state to be used with BottomNavigationBar is state_checked not state_selected.